# I plugged my smartphone to be charged using a car charging adapter. My phone will not turn back on at all!

Tags: charging

Have I ruined my phone?  I plugged my smartphone into my car charger no light appeared so I brought inside tried it there still no light and now my phone will not go back on!  Help!

Answer (score 1):

Is the car charger of good quality? I would try removjng battery,  putting it back in, plug it to wall, wait a few minutes and press and hold down power button

Answer (score 0):

I feel it's not good to charge from car battery except in very emergency conditions. Even if you charge, you should use a good charger. Many times, there may be a surge or voltage drop in your battery when you start the car or use the air-conditioning systems, which if not protected by charger, will ruin your phone. It's much better if you buy a power bank for these cases.

Anyways, try taking the battery out, and reinstalling it. If that doesn't work, you may buy a new battery or try out with someone else's. If that doesn't work either, you should take your phone to a service centre.